# How to note salary when I can't indicate part-time status?

Tags: salary, applications, united-states, part-time

Some recent positions of mine were part-time, but salaried (i.e., not for an hourly wage. I was hired for a certain number of hours per week, but often worked more).

Some online job applications are fill-in forms that leave no room to indicate whether my most recent position was full-time, but ask me for its salary/wage.  Should I answer with the actual salary, the pro rata full-time equivalent, or the pro rata hourly-wage equivalent? If the full-time equivalent, should I use 35 or 40 hours per week as full time?  I'm located in the United States.

Answer (score 2):

Since the form prohibits you from being absolutely accurate, I would put in an hourly rate because it most accurately communicates to the reviewer what your pay level was. A part-time salary could cause someone to miscalculate your value to the previous employer since the part-time status is not noted (and a part-time notation might not indicate number of hours per week either).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I indicate the actual salary, the pro rata full-time
>   equivalent, or the pro rata hourly-wage equivalent?

Since the applications are asking for salary, you should simply indicate your salary. Anything else would provide numbers that aren't real, and don't answer the question being asked.

You resume should indicate that the job was part-time. That way, the recruiter or hiring manager can put the two data points together for a complete picture of your situation.

Some applications ask for "Desired Salary" - that's where you should indicate the full-time salary you are seeking (if indeed you are seeking a full-time position).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the question wasn't clear, but some online job applications are fill-in forms with slots for specific information, and some don't allow room for specifying part-time status. It's those cases I'm asking about. Do I need to edit the question?

Comment: I've edited the question in light of my preceding comment on this answer.

Comment: I'd consider the per-hour value a real number.

Comment: @CodesInChaos probably not for a salaried role is indicating you where hourly paid Is going to be a negative  here

Answer (score 0):

You should, where possible, be precise.  For example, put "£19.15 per hour / 45 hours per week."

If it is just asking for your annual equivalent salary, you should calculate it based on what you *have* been paid.

For example, if over the last month you worked 150 hours and were paid £19.15/hour - your annual salary would be £34,500.